# Storing complex objects passed by servlet into an array in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet that passes an ArrayList into a jsp page that receives it and places it in an Array, but i can't access the parameters inside Loc if i store them in an array like this:

```
var locations = new Array();
<c:forEach items="${photosName}" var="photo" varStatus="loop">
    locations["${loop.index}"] = "${photo}";
</c:forEach>
```

the variable photo contains attributes like latitude, longitude and accuracy that i wish to store in the locations array. But if i store them like this how can i access them in other parts of code.

Example of what i want to do:

```
locations[i].latitude
locations[i].longitude
locations[i].accuracy
```

Any help is welcome :)

Tried this now:

```
var locations = new Array();
<c:forEach items="${photosName}" var="photo" varStatus="loop">
    locations["${loop.index}"] = JSON.stringify("${photo}");
</c:forEach>
alert("latitude: "+locations[0].latitude+ " longitude: "+locations[0].longitude);
```

It printed latitude: undefined longitude: undefined. Do i need to import something for the json.stringify to work?

Photo object in jsp is represented by this class:

```
@Entity
public class Loc implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private long time;
    private double accuracy;
    private int processed;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return this.longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "latitude: " + latitude + " longitude: " + longitude + "time: "
                + time;
    }

    public double getAccuracy() {
        return accuracy;
    }

    public void setAccuracy(double accuracy) {
        this.accuracy = accuracy;
    }

    public int getProcessed() {
        return processed;
    }

    public void setProcessed(int processed) {
        this.processed = processed;
    }
}
```

Comment: From where are u getting your photo object (which java object)?

Comment: Lets say that you have list of java objects which called `photoList`. what you need to do now is to convert javascript. Try this: `var photo list = JSON.stringify(<%gson.toJson(photoList).toString%>)`

Comment: yes, it is how you convert the java list to javascript array

Comment: it gives me an error in the toString part, Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression

Comment: see my edited answer, it should be: `var photo list = JSON.stringify(<%=gson...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `locations["${loop.index}"] = {JSON.stringify("${photo}")};`. Then you can access the attributes as you wrote:

```
locations[i].latitude
locations[i].longitude
locations[i].accuracy
```

**Note:** photo is a string representation of a JSONObject. Like this:

```
JSONObject jsonPhoto = gson.toJson(photoObj) //photoObj is instance of your java photo object class
String photo = jsonPhoto.toString();
```

For converting an object to json object you can use GSON library. Here is [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) to a nice tutorial.

If you have list of Java `phtoObjects` you can do like this in your servlet:

```
<%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson" %>   
<%GSON gson = new Gson();%>    
var photoArray = JSON.stringify(<%=gson.toJson(phtoObjects).toString()%>);
```

Comment: i tried this: var locations = new Array();
  <c:forEach items="${photosName}" var="photo" varStatus="loop">
   locations["${loop.index}"] = JSON.stringify("${photo}");
  </c:forEach>
  alert("latitude: "+locations[0].latitude+ " longitude: "+locations[0].longitude); And the result was undefined

Comment: Please add this code to your question, so it can be easier to read.

Comment: did you add the GSON library to your project?

Comment: I added it to my project into java built path -> libraries. How can i put it in the jsp page?

Comment: you need to import it to the jsp file, add this `<%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson" %>` at the top of your jsp file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47019/discussion-between-joaofilipeclementemartins-and-vlad-ioffe)